# I have a custom js function with name remove() and it works in all browsers except chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, conflict

I googed about it and found that it seems to be a reserved keyword in chrome because of which it conflicts with my code's remove(). Is there a workaround which can make this work without actually changing the name at all places

Comment: Try showing us some code ...

Comment: That's weird  I can't see a 'remove' function in my chrome console (I do get removeEventListener but that's different) . But in any case , it might be easier to just replace the name rather than starting to write conditions etc.

Answer (score 0):

Today, during a class, I was with the same problem.
I did a sample code that demonstrated how to apply the method removeChild in JS.
It works in all browser except chrome. I just changed the name of the function and it's all ok. A user function named **remove** don't works. See the code.

Best regards.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script>
    function remover(){ 
      var itemRemover = document.getElementById("numero").value;
      var item=document.getElementById(itemRemover);
      var lista=document.getElementById("lista");
      lista.removeChild(item);
      document.getElementById("numero").value="";     
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
       <ul id="lista">
          <li id="1">Ford</li>
          <li id="2">GM</li>
          <li id="3">Honda</li>
       </ul>    
        <input type="text" id="numero" />
        <input type="button" value="Remove by Id" 
               onclick="remover();" />
    </body>
    </html>
```